# Is "attemptee" actually a word?

Tags: is-it-a-word

I've seen the word [online](https://www.google.com.tw/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CFQQFjAJ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fshanghaiist.com%2F2011%2F10%2F15%2Famerican_woman_jumps_into_west_lake_1.php&ei=rKplVKC3HOG-mwW_yIGIDg&usg=AFQjCNFsgN8w-zhjE7XN6EU2p9GULTqlNA&sig2=9_jrF1Tpc4yOzOkuzGFVNQ):

> American woman jumps into West Lake to save **suicide attemptee**...

But then I tried the [dictionary](https://www.google.com.tw/search?es_sm=122&q=define%3Aattemptee&oq=define%3Aattemptee&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.0.41313.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..58.serp..0.0.0.oSsEbzIxxaM) and didn't get any results.

Is attemptee actually a word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It clearly refers to someone who attempted suicide.

I think it is an attempt to coin a new word in line with trainer/trainee, but it is not a common one.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=attemptee%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cattemptee%3B%2Cc0) shows no significant use of the term.

M- W defines [attempter](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/attempter) as: one who attempts suicide

Comment: I suppose that an attemptee is someone whom an attempter makes an attempt upon. And in the case of attempted suicide, the attempter and the attemptee are the same person.

Comment: Yes, the issue is about how common  the term 'attemptee' is, which, as explained, I think it is not.

Comment: So what synonym do we have to get the context out of suicidal attempt, lets say a person who makes a login attempt, can we call him attempter?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to use the word Attempter is more appropriate than than attemptee which is really not yet acceptable in the English vocabulary but may find its way there if people are persistent in its use.

One who attempts an act
, is an AttemptER not an AttemptEE.
You may want to consider one who pays for something, the one is the PayER and not the payEE. The one that is paid or about to be paid is the payEE.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).